# How to get the Workspace ID of an Azure Log Analytics workspace via C#

Tags: azure

How can I get the Workspace ID of a Log Analytics workspace in Azure via C#?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've since found that the `OperationalInsightsManagementClient` class can be used as well.

```
var client = new OperationalInsightsManagementClient(GetCredentials()) {SubscriptionId = subscriptionId};
return (await client.Workspaces.ListByResourceGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroupName))
    .Body
    .Select(w => w.CustomerId)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: In case others wonder, it's Microsoft.Azure.Management.OperationalInsights package

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no Log Analytics C# SDK to get the Workspace ID, my workaround is to get the access token vai `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication`, then call the REST API [Workspaces - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspaces/get#code-try-0), the `customerId` in the response is the Workspace ID which you need.

**My working sample:**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallWebAPIAsync().Wait();

        }

        static async Task CallWebAPIAsync()
        {
            AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/").Result;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/");


                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //GET Method  
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourcegroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/<workspace name>?api-version=2015-11-01-preview");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

For more details about the authentication, you could take a look at this [**link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#local-development-authentication).